# Adding a newly created object into an array in swift

Tags: java, arrays, swift, oop, object

I decided to start a project in java to get a rough outline of how the program was to function before I started to program it in swift(a language I am completely unfamiliar with) whilst trying to convert the code I've ran into an issue and cannot even understand how I've gone wrong. This is context for the code

```
public class Item {
    private String name;
    private double price;

    public Item(String name,double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
public class Account{
    public ArrayList<Item> ItemsList = new ArrayList<Item>();
   
    public Account() {
        this.ItemsList = newArrayList<Item>();
    }

    public void addItem(String name,double price) {
        ItemsList.add(new Item(name,price))
    }
```

In Swift I've got this far

```
class Item {
    
    var name:String
    var price:Double
    
    init(name:String,price:Double) {
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
    }
}

class Account {

    var ItemsList:Array<Item>

    init() {
        self.ItemsList = []
    }

    func addItem(name: String,price: Double){
        ItemsList.append(Item(name: String,price: Double))
    }

}
```

but the final line

`ItemsList.append(Item(name: String,price: Double))`

is returning an error when running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here

```
func addItem(name: String, price: Double){
     ItemsList.append(Item(name: String,price: Double)) //<-- Problem
}
```

Look at it JAVA code:

```
public void addItem(String name,double price) {
       ItemsList.add(new Item(name,price) //<-- Here
}
```

Your passing name and price as a value parameter, not a data type.

Why you get an error? It because when you call any function you need to pass value instead of Data Type

The correct syntex is :

```
func addItem(name: String, price: Double){
    ItemsList.append(Item(name: name, price: price)) //<-- Solution
}
```

If you want to JAVA type constructor syntax style, you can use underscore like this,

```
class Item {
    var name: String
    var price: Double
    init(_ name:String, _ price:Double) {
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
    }
}

class Account {
    var itemsList: [Item] = []
    
    init() {
    }
    
    func addItem(name: String, price: Double){
        itemsList.append(Item(name, price))
    }
    
}
```

Note: Variable name must start with lower case. More: https://google.github.io/swift/

Comment: Thank you very much I'm finding the syntax of swift to be quite confusing so far.

Comment: @Raja Kishan: Minor point, but it's not true that variable names must start with lower case. It's arguably a near-universal convention, but it's not a language requirement or a hard rule.

Comment: Rules are made for some purpose and in some special cases you can avoid to follow those rules.

Comment: Your “The Problem is here” code is actually correct. I guess it’s a copy/paste mistake. Regarding variable names I agree with both, I think it’s better to use the word should rather than must but it’s a strong should

Comment: Oh yes, @JoakimDanielson. Thanks for the correction.